# How can I change time format string with regex in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want this string:

```
var time = '02/19/2014';
```

to look like:

```
var time = '20140219';
```

That is, I want the format mm/dd/yyyy to "be regexed" into yyyymmdd.

Comment: Why not convert it with the Date object rather then a Regex?

Comment: Why a RE? `time = time.substr(6, 4) + time.substr(0, 2) + time.substr(3, 2)`

Comment: @AlexK. This worked like a charm. I thought I had to use regex for this but this was much cleaner. If you write it as an answer I can accept it. I know it doesn't answer my question per se, since I asked for regex but I think it's important to show that the questionaire thought regex was necessary but someone provided a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about some simple string manipulation?

```
time = time.substr(6, 4) + time.substr(0, 2) + time.substr(3, 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var time = '02/19/2014';
time = time.replace(/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/, '$3$1$2');
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, string consists of three blocks, divided by slashes. I propose you to do the following: pattern as (\d{2}) / (\d{2}) / (\d{4}), and replacement as $3$1$2 (without spaces). It is written in php, but I hope that you can easily convert it into your language.